# Embedding a react native inside Cordova App

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cordova, cordova-plugins

we want to build new functionality in React Native but the main app is cordova app.

current production app created in cordova. but is it possible to call production cordova app to React Native app?

example: cordova app->Footer menu  button click-> trigger/invoke the React Native screens

1. is it possible to embedding a react native inside existing cordova app?.

we have an app build using cordova. However, the client is not happy about the performance.  so we like to build new screens in react-native and we thought about combining the current state of the app, embedding a react native inside cordova app. Does this make any sense?

Comment: If you want to improve performance, embedding another framework wouldn't be the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: it is complex app we required to know any existing approach is there so we can try to  check the flow.

Comment: how we can embedded the mutiple app as single app.

Comment: I don't know - it's not something I've ever heard of. I think it's a bad idea. Performance issues are usually caused by your code and not the framework. Use profiling tools to see what is causing the issues.

Comment: Are you getting any solution of above?
We are also having a very big Cordova Application and now wants to migrate our application to React native but with gradual approach not directly rewrite everything from Cordova to React?